# Stable local minimizers of functions on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ be a lower semicontinuous function. We are interested in  some conceptions of local minimizer:

- We say that  $\bar{x}\in X$ is a **stable strict local minimizer** of $f$ if $f(\bar{x})$ is finite and there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the mapping
  $$
   M:x^*\mapsto\text{argmin}_{\|x-\bar{x}\|\leq\varepsilon}\{f(x)-\langle x^*,x\rangle\}
   $$
  from $X^*$ to $X$ is single-valued on some neighborhood of $0$ with $M(0)=\bar{x}$.
- We say that  $\bar{x}\in X$ is a **stable well posed local minimizer** of $f$ if $f(\bar{x})$ is finite and there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every vector $x^*\in X^*$ near the origin, there is a point $x_{x^*}$ in $U:=\overline{B}(\bar{x},\varepsilon)$ with $x_0=\bar{x}$ so that in terms of the perturbed functions $f_{x^*}(\cdot):=f(\cdot)-\langle x^*,\cdot\rangle$ we have
  $$
   f_{x^*}(x_{x^*})=\inf_{x\in U}f_{x^*}(x)
   $$
  and every sequence $(x_n)\subset U$ along which $f_{x^*}(x_n)\rightarrow f_{x^*}(x_{x^*})$ obeys $\|x_n-x_{x^*}\|\rightarrow 0$.
- We say that  $\bar{x}\in X$ is a **stable strong local minimizer** of $f$ if $f(\bar{x})$ is finite and there exist $\varepsilon>0$ and $\kappa>0$ such that for every vector $x^*\in X^*$ near the origin, there is a point $x_{x^*}$ in $U:=\overline{B}(\bar{x},\varepsilon)$ with $x_0=\bar{x}$ so that in terms of the perturbed functions $f_{x^*}:=f(\cdot)-\langle x^*,\cdot\rangle$ the inequality
  $$
   f_{x^*}(x)\geq f_{x^*}(x_{x^*})+\kappa\|x-x_{x^*}\|^2
   $$
  holds for every $x\in U$.
- A point $\bar{x}\in X$ is called a **stable Lipschitz local minimizer** of the function $f$ if $f(\bar{x})$ is finite and there exists  $\varepsilon>0$ such that the mapping
  $$
   M:x^*\mapsto\text{argmin}_{\|x-\bar{x}\|\leq\varepsilon}\{f(x)-\langle x^*,x\rangle\}
   $$
  is single-valued and Lipschitz continuous on some neighborhood of $0$ with $M(0)=\bar{x}$.

**We have observed that:**

- stable strong local minimizer $\Rightarrow$ stable well posed local minimizer $\Rightarrow$ stable strict local minimizer.
- stable strong local minimizer $\Rightarrow$ stable Lipschitz local minimizer $\Rightarrow$ stable strict local minimizer.
- When $X$ is finite dimensional,  stable strict local minimizer $\Leftrightarrow$ stable well posed local minimizer.
- When $X$ is finite dimensional,  stable strong local minimizer $\Leftrightarrow$ stable Lipschitz local minimizer.

**We would like to construct:**

- a stable well posed local minimizer of $f$ which is not a stable strong local minimizer of $f$
- a stable strict local minimizer of $f$ which is not a stable well posed local minimizer of $f$
- a stable Lipschitz local minimizer of $f$ which is not a stable strong local minimizer of $f$
- a stable Lipschitz local minimizer of $f$ which is not a stable well posed local minimizer of $f$
- a stable well posed local minimizer of $f$ which is not a stable Lipschitz local minimizer of $f$

Thank you for all kind help and comments.

Comment: Just for your information here stable Lipschitz local minimizer is known as tilt stability in literatures. I think the function $f(x) = x^4$ is satisfying stable well posed local minimizer condition at $x=0$ but not Tilt stability. Am I right?

Comment: I am waiting for the complete solution for my question. Thank you for all kind comments.